# CVS list of files only in working directories

Tags: cvs

Is it possible to get a list of files that are in the working directory tree, but not in the current branch/tag? I currently diff the working copy with another directory updated to the same module and tag/branch but without the local non-repo files. It works, but doesn't honor the .cvsignore files. I figure there *must* be an option using a variation of 'cvs diff'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project has:

```
dir/a.txt       <--- In CVS
    b.txt       <--- In CVS
    c.txt       <--- In CVS
    newfile.txt <---- ***NOT IN CVS***
```

Then the following command will identify newfile.txt for you:

```
cvs -n update | egrep '^?'
```

Comment: No, not files added (in the cvs sense), but files that are merely present in the directory structure and perhaps _should_ be added. I want to wade through various temp files scattered around and add the important stuff to the project on the repository

Comment: I clarified my answer with an example.

Comment: How daft of me! Thanks for the tip. I was so sure that I needed to use the diff functionality that I not only overlooked the functionality in the update command, but also your advice to use the update command.